# CalendarStrip Style changes when setting scrollable to true

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

So I am making a `CalendarStrip` from react-native-calendar-strip. Basically when I am setting the scrollable to true in the `CalendrStrip`, the height of the strip gets shortened and ruins the look of the `CalendarStrip`.
[image]

So this is the `CalendarStrip` without scrollable set to true.

[image]

This is when I set the scrollable to true. As you can see, the height of the Strip is reduced and that's why the highlighted date is getting cut off. I do not understand why this is happening.

```
<View style={styles.listContainer}>
<CalendarStrip
            scrollable={true}
            scrollToOnSelectedDate={true}
            ref={calenderRef}
            headerText={' '}
            selectedDate={newdate}
            onDateSelected={value => {
              setDate(moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
              setSelectedMonth(value.month());
              setSelectedYear(value.year());
              console.log(newdate);
            }}
            getSelectedDate={value => console.log(value)}
            daySelectionAnimation={{
              type: 'border',
              duration: 200,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderHighlightColor: 'white',
            }}
            calendarHeaderStyle={{
              fontSize: 1,
              fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular',
              color: 'black',
              alignSelf: 'flex-start',
            }}
            //   iconLeftStyle={{position:"absolute",top:-70}}
            //  iconRightStyle={{color:'white',backgroundColor:colors.primaryTheme,}}
            style={{
              width: '98%',
              height: 150,
              paddingTop: 20,
              paddingBottom: 10,
            }}
            startDate={moment(date)}
            highlightDateContainerStyle={{
              backgroundColor: colors.secondary,
              paddingVertical: 10,
              height: 80,
              color: 'white',
            }}
            dayContainerStyle={{paddingVertical: 10}}
            highlightDateNumberStyle={{
              color: colors.white,
              fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium',
              fontSize: 14,
            }}
            highlightDateNameStyle={{
              color: colors.white,
              fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium',
              fontSize: 12,
              marginHorizontal: 1.5,
              padding: 5.5,
              borderTopEndRadius: 20,
              borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
              borderTopRightRadius: 20,
            }}
            highlightDateNumberContainerStyle={{
              backgroundColor: colors.primaryTheme,
              borderRadius: 40,
              padding: 4,
              marginHorizontal: 10,
              minWidth: 30,
              minHeight: 30,
            }}
          />
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try raising the maxDayComponentSize, which defaults at 80. It fixed the issue for me.

`maxDayComponentSize={200}`